# References for loop rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory

I recently saw a paper on alternative loop rings, as always, I am interested in all kinds of rings, and new kind of ring looked attractive. I would like to read loop and then loop rings in detail from basics of loops. Is there any text which has included these algebraic structures in details, or some book on loops or loop rings only. I found an ebook by Goodaire and Jespers named [Alternative loop rings](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=rty4EbgL2WgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=alternative+loop+rings&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KVtjVbCuIIOwuATmuoPYAQ&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=alternative%20loop%20rings&f=false), but it only works with Moufang loop rings as I quickly went through first two chapters to see what is what?

Is there any other book, or text, which deals with general loops, or discuss various kinds of loop, because I am familiar with rings, but not with loops, so first I would like to grasp concept of loops. Then concept of loop rings will be a lot like group rings, I guess!!

Thanx in advance

Comment: I nixed the ([tag:loop-rings]) tag because it seems to be a *very* specialized topic which isn't likely to come up very often.

Comment: No problem. But I am gonna read them, I think, caught my interest, so "there will be questions!!!"

Comment: If you do end up having multiple questions on this site about them (more than five?), I do suggest you make the tag. You might end up bringing a lot of attention to the topic around these parts. I definitely had never heard of it before.

Comment: Yes Cameron. Correct.

Comment: Here are some good notes I just found: http://www.math.mun.ca/~edgar/history.pdf. These seem to be good notes on alternative loop rings: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CD8QFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.wisc.edu%2F~kunen%2Floopring.ps&ei=qV1jVfSwG9H3yQTflYDIAg&usg=AFQjCNEBODqTSeq1J-pYLC-mYI6sx1_MHQ&bvm=bv.93990622,d.aWw&cad=rja

Answer (score 2):

You could start by reading the article [A brief history of loop rings](http://www.math.mun.ca/~edgar/history.pdf) by E. G. Goodaire and trace back the papers citing this one.
See also [Advances in loop rings and their loops](http://www.math.md/files/qrs/v15-n1/v15-n1-(pp1-18).pdf) from the same author.